# Does jquery AJAX "cache" parameter respond to my needs?

Tags: c#, php, jquery, asp.net, ajax

Currently I'm using this function, but it can only refresh the whole #comments div.

```
$.ajax({
   url: 'WebForm1.aspx',
   success: function (data) {
   $("WebForm1.aspx #comments").html(data);
   }
});
```

I'm trying to figure out if jQuery AJAX can detect any difference between what the user is actively viewing a webpage, and what is coming from the database, so whenever someone adds a comment, the visitors see the incoming comment as fading in, rather than the whole #comments div getting refreshed periodically.

Here is the workflow that I wish:

AJAX request 1 -> jquery fetches Data A , Data B , Data C and displays them in the #comments on the browser, saves it in its cache.

(Data D is added into the db a few while later)

AJAX request 2 -> jquery fetches Data A , Data B , Data C **and Data D**, compares with the cache on the browser and detects that Data D was absent in the previous version of #comments, and fades in only the new Data D.

How can I do this? Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither jQuery nor jQuery.ajax are able (or meant) to do what you're asking. The comparison logic must be done by yourself.

I have a couple of suggestions:

1. The call to the server for your data should accept a timestamp parameter. If the parameter isn't set, return the whole set of comments, including a timestamp with the current time. If the timestamp parameter is set, find the comments that were posted since then, send only those along, again with a timestamp of the current time. The timestamp from the server is saved on the client, and sent along with every subsequent request. This way, you always receive only new comments. Append those new comments to the screen at the desired position and with the desired animation.
2. The above requires quite some changes. If you're not able to do this, use your current code. Whenever comments are loaded, search the dom for the first element with the data-comment_id attribute. The value of this attribute is the highest comment id (assuming you can't re-order the comments, otherwise your check needs to be more robust). In the success callback, search the data parameter(which is html) for elements with the data-comment_id attribute, and throw away everything after the element with data-comment_id value of 1 higher than the highest comment id you had so far. Append the html you have left to the dom with the desired animation.

Hope that helps you get on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

You will need some sort of setInterval to continuously figure out what the latest comment was and fetch new data after the newest comments' ID

**JS**

```
// check every ten seconds
setInterval(function() {

    // figure out most recent comment and pass it to the URL so your query can search for anything greater than newest_comment
    $.ajax({
        url: 'WebForm1.aspx',
        type: 'GET',
        data: {'newest_comment':$('#comments').find('span.comment:eq(0)').data('comment_id')}, // newest_comment would be 5
        dataType: 'HTML',
        success: function (data) {
            $("#comments").prepend(data);
        }
    });

}, 10000);
```

**Possible HTML**

```
<div id="comments">
    <span class="comment" data-comment_id="5"></span>
    <span class="comment" data-comment_id="4"></span>
    <span class="comment" data-comment_id="3"></span>
    <span class="comment" data-comment_id="2"></span>
    <span class="comment" data-comment_id="1"></span>
</div>
```